# Is it possible to separate databases in WordPress site - one for orders and the other for all non-orders related

Tags: database, backup

I am new to WP but already encountered a rogue plugin which completely messed parts of my database ( it was a media library folders management plugin). I would happily restore the site back to before the plugin was installed but that course would also loose any Woocommerce orders I got accumulated during that day.
So I am looking for a way to have my orders stored somewhere which is safe and the rest is in another database which I can easily restore from a backup (and thus loose no orders).
I realise that orders are just posts and are related to other posts (like images) and their IDs, which still will reside in the "non-safe" database. But since I think such a scheme would reduce the risk and lower the impact tremendously upon a restore from backup event on the non-safe database - I am looking for such a configuration. Is it possible to do in WordPress ?

Comment: It’s not clear from your post what you are using for your orders. What’s creating and storing your orders? How has the media library Plugin affected your orders?

Comment: if it is losing order information you are concerned about, setting up an hourly backup of the orders post type in the posts table rather than trying to create a duplicate or separate table would be safer than any single database table.